# R-Shiny server function doesn't work. I got an error "object not found"

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have 2 almost identical reactive functions in the SERVER part of my shinyapp. Well there are more than 2, but those describe the problem:

```
  ventas_tbl_react <- reactive({

    DF_react() %>%
      select(Periodo, tenant_id, `ventas | valor`) %>%
      group_by(tenant_id) %>%
      mutate(`vs Promedio` = round(`ventas | valor` /
                                   mean(`ventas | valor`, na.rm = T) - 1,
                                   digits = 2)) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      group_by(.data = ., Periodo) %>%
      summarise(`vs Promedio` = mean(`vs Promedio`, na.rm = T)) %>%
      ungroup()

  })


  clientes_tbl_react <- reactive({

    DF_react() %>%
      select(Periodo, tenant_id, `cantidad de clientes`) %>%
      group_by(tenant_id) %>%
      mutate(`vs Promedio` = round(`cantidad de clientes` /
                                   mean(`cantidad de clientes`, na.rm = T) - 1,
                                   digits = 2)) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      group_by(.data = ., Periodo) %>%
      summarise(`vs Promedio` = mean(`vs Promedio`, na.rm = T)) %>%
      ungroup()

  })
```

I tried to create a function so I don't have que repeat the same code over and over again:

```
tbl_react_funct <- function(var) {

    DF_react() %>%
      select(Periodo, tenant_id, var) %>%
      group_by(tenant_id) %>%
      mutate(`vs Promedio` = round(var / mean(var, na.rm = T) - 1,
                                   digits = 2)) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      group_by(Periodo) %>%
      summarise(`vs Promedio` = mean(`vs Promedio`, na.rm = T)) %>% 
      ungroup()

  }


  ventas_tbl_react <- reactive({

    tbl_react_funct(var = `ventas | valor`)

  })
```

I got this `ERROR: object 'ventas | valor' not found`. I also tried creating another argument (data) but it didn't work.

Comment: you are passing your column name as an object to your function